# Creating a file upload field with a translatable title attribute field

Tags: files, i18n-l10n

I have a File field with the title attribute enabled and I'm trying to figure out how to make the title attribute field translatable using entity translations without affecting the actual file field itself. I'd prefer to allow users to upload one file with a title attribute that can be translated.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was I used `hook_i18n_string_info` to define a new "Captions" text group, `hook_field_widget_form_alter` to attach a new process function to the desired upload widgets, and my callback for `hook_field_widget_form_alter` cloned the title field (into title_fr for me), then also checked to see if #default_value was a string and used `i18n_string_translate` to update title_fr's default_value.

What I did and wouldn't recommend doing was I put the translation handling in the submit function for my form. In there I constructed my translation "name" using `caption:$field_key::$nid::$field_delta` and then calling `i18n_string_translation_update($name, $french_caption, 'fr', $english_caption)`.

Comment: Nice solution, I did the same and just exchanged the submit function for hook_entity_presave().